# import hmmpytk package in python

Tags: python, import, package

I import hmmpytk package and control modules with this code :

```
import pkgutil

import hmmpytk

package=hmmpytk

for importer, modname, ispkg in     pkgutil.walk_packages(path=package.__path__,prefix=package.__name__+'.',onerror=    lambda x: None):
    print(modname)
```

hmmpytk.hmmpytk

hmmpytk.hmmpytk.hmm

hmmpytk.hmmpytk.hmm_faster

hmmpytk.hmmpytk.test

Partial code :

```
from hmmpytk import hmmpytk 

hmm_model = hmmpytk.hmm_faster.HMM()
```

And getting following error :

> 'module' object has no attribute 'hmm_faster'

i don't know how can i import and use this package .

Comment: What is 'hmmpytk'? A class? If so, are those class methods or instance methods?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a class or not.  hmmpytk folder includes four file with py extension. And i get it from this    site:https://code.google.com/p/hmmpytk/wiki/Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I think I found your problem. Give this a shot:

```
from hmmpytk import hmm_faster

hmm_model = hmm_faster.HMM()
```

Comment: cannot import name 'hmm_faster'

Comment: You need to install the package first, which needs to be available to the python interpreter.